# Перегрузить операцию умножения для метода нахождения скалярного произведения

Tags: c++

Как осуществить перегрузку, если в умножении участвует три переменные? Что-то попытался написать, но не компилируется.

```
int Vectors2::find_scalar_product(int vector_coordinates[], int vector_coordinates2[])
{
    Vectors2::scalar_product = (vector_coordinates[0]*vector_coordinates2[0]) + (vector_coordinates[1]*vector_coordinates2[1]) + (vector_coordinates[2]*vector_coordinates2[2]);
}
```

```
    сlass Vectors
    {
        public:
            /*...*/
        protected:
            int coordinates[3];

    };

    class Vectors2 : public Vectors
    {
        public:
            Vectors2 operator*(int coordinate[])
            {
                return Vectors2(vector_coordinates[] * coordinate[]);
            }

            Vectors2 operator*(int coordinate[]);
            int find_scalar_product(int [], int[];)

        private:
            int coordinates2[3];
            int scalar_product;
    };
```

Comment: а вы сами скажите что это такое:  vector_coordinates[]* coordinate[] ?

Comment: @Shinkiro Судя по всему, Вы не до конца понимаете, что такое скалярное произведение, и что такое перегрузка операторов. В скалярном произведении участвуют всегда две и только две переменные.